# Microsoft Access query is too complex - IF formula

Tags: microsoft-access, runtime-error

I have a query in Access Database and when I try to run it, I get an error message "query is too complex to run." Runtime error 3360." The problem is with one formula / programming logic, see below:

Previously the formula was the below - and it worked.

```
IIf([BegTaxBasis]=0 And [Contribution]+[Distribution]=0,0,IIf([BegTaxBasis]=0 And [TaxIncSubTotal]=0,-[Distribution],IIf([Distribution]=0,0,IIf([TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]<[Distribution],-[Distribution],0))))
```

A verbose version of the above would be:

```
IIf(
    [BegTaxBasis]=0 And [Contribution]+[Distribution]=0,
    0,
    IIf(
        [BegTaxBasis]=0 And [TaxIncSubTotal]=0,
        -[Distribution],
        IIf(
            [Distribution]=0,
            0,
            IIf(
                [TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]<[Distribution],
                -[Distribution],
                0
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Then I updated it to, see below:

```
IIf([BegTaxBasis]=0 And [Contribution]+[Distribution]=0,0,IIf([BegTaxBasis]=0 And [TaxIncSubTotal]=0,-[Distribution],IIf([Distribution]=0,0,IIf([TBBLL]>0,0,IIf([TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]<[Distribution],-[Distribution],IIf([TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]>[Distribution] And [TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]<0 And [TaxIncSubTotal]<0,[TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]-[TaxIncSubTotal],[TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse])))))
```

Verbose version of the above:

```
IIf(
    [BegTaxBasis]=0 And [Contribution]+[Distribution]=0,
    0,
    IIf(
        [BegTaxBasis]=0 And [TaxIncSubTotal]=0,
        -[Distribution],
        IIf(
            [Distribution]=0,
            0,
            IIf(
                [TBBLL]>0,
                0,
                IIf(
                    [TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]<[Distribution],
                    -[Distribution],
                    IIf(
                        [TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]>[Distribution] And [TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]<0 And [TaxIncSubTotal]<0,
                        [TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]-[TaxIncSubTotal],
                        [TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

And now the query wont run, any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: A case statement might work better, in that it would be more readable.  You query appears to be missing an ).

Comment: Case statement is not recognized in Access Expression, also, I don't think its missing a ")" because Access returns an error if a parenthesis is missing. Any other way to simplify the IF statement ?

Comment: Well ... the Complex error can be cased by sooooo many different things: overly complex expressions, function calls with null values, incomplete date parameters (eg #07-25-# ,etc) and so one.

Comment: Why are you using `iif`? I mean what is the point?

Comment: As you can see from my edit to your question, you're indeed missing a closing parenthesis. If you do have that in your original code your copy for the question is incomplete. As you're using that unwieldy computation (`[TBBLL]+[Recourse]+[QualifiedNonrecourse]+[NonRecourse]`) multiple times, did you think about using a variable/column or something similar?